# datatype check in prompt checkbox javascript

Tags: javascript, types, prompt

How do I check input from prompt box if it has a number in it in javascript??

```
var name=prompt("enter your name");
```

In this case i should not have a number in name how do I check this condition???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var name = prompt(...) || '';
if (name.match(/\d/))
   alert("you can't use numbers in your name");
```